# Issue in displaying static Google maps

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

The src property for the img tag is

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=1701 Fm Rd 1187, Mansfield, Tx &size=150x90&sensor=false&zoom=15&maptype=roadmap" + "&markers=size:tiny|color:blue|1701 Fm Rd 1187, Mansfield, Tx
```

[image]

Comment: works fine for me http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=1701%20Fm%20Rd%201187,%20Mansfield,%20Tx%20&size=150x90&sensor=false&zoom=15&maptype=roadmap%22%20+%20%22&markers=size:tiny|color:blue|1701%20Fm%20Rd%201187,%20Mansfield,%20Tx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine from here. You have simply exceeded the usage limits from your IP address:

> Use of the Google Static Maps API is subject to a query limit of 1000 unique (different) image requests per viewer per day.
>
> Since this restriction is a quota per viewer, most developers should not need to worry about exceeding their quota. However, note that we enforce an additional request rate limit to prevent abuse of the service. Requests of identical images, in general, do not count towards this limit beyond the original request.

Further reading:

- [Static Maps API V2 Developer Guide - Usage Limits](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits)

Comment: I expected that this would be the reason but i still wonder how i have requested 1000 unique(different) image requests within a day!!! when i was working from localhost i never faced this problem, yesterday we have hosted the website in internal server for testing purpose and we have faced this problem. Here, unique request means request from same IP address or from same machine? Same IP address means all developers and testers will use same IP address since the application is hosted on server which is available in intranet! Is getting a license for Google map only solution to this problem?

Comment: @banupriyavijay: Yes it is per IP address, and therefore you and your colleagues are sharing the same quota. If you have multiple static IP addresses assigned to you by your ISP, you could configure your router to use different IP addresses for different workstations.

Comment: We faced problems with this part. Daily after the first half of the day the Google map does not get displayed. We are worried that Google might block our IP, so we have removed Google maps from the website!!!! :(

Comment: Because of the above mentioned issue, we have removed Google map and   started implementing Yahoo maps in our website since Yahoo AJAX Maps API is limited to 50,000 queries per IP per day
(http://developer.yahoo.com/search/rate.html) which is better than Google Map!!! :-)