# Bypass Google Geocoding API IP Rate Limits

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

We are a division of a large corporation and are running into a MAJOR problem with the Google maps and geocoding API. The problem is that all 70 divisions of our corporation are behind the same IP address. So a customer service agent in India would appear to be coming from the same IP address as a developer in Cleveland, OH who would appear to be coming from the same IP address as a division president in western Europe. With over 130,000 employees, we routinely get blocked for exceeding the IP rate limit.

Aside from individuals just browsing to websites that happen to be using Google maps with client-side geocoding requests, any division that attempts to do batch geocoding or provides their own application for showing maps will all contribute to the same limit! We actually use our own Where To Buy service internally, which is publicly available, (http://www.ridgid.com/Tools/Where-To-Buy/), to give customers information about local distributors.

While we are not running into an API limit (at least not yet, and when we do we can always buy the enterprise license), we are running into the IP rate limit and currently have no workaround. We are already following best practices in terms of caching up geocoding results and reducing wasteful calls. Thankfully this isn't a problem for our customers as they are not on the same IP as users within our corporation.

The question is whether there is ANY way we can get an exception from Google to our specific IP address to improve the IP-based limitations given our setup? This is really a question for Google. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would suggest contacting Google's Map for Business team directly:

http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/request.py?&utm_campaign=en-codepremier&contact_type=gme

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Although the google forums say to post questions here now.

Comment: Yes, but in terms of licensing, you should contact the Google Maps for Business team.  Your question is not really technical in nature--you're asking a business question.

Comment: I just found something interesting in the Google API Console. You can set a parameter for maximum requests per user per second to your API. The default is 1 request per second per user (aka IP address). While I don't think this is the issue we were running into, I think that updating this to be a higher number (e.g. 100 instead of 1) might help reduce the likelihood of running into problems from internal usage of our public site.

Comment: Hypothetically we could get blocked just from individuals browsing to sites that are using google maps--regardless of whether we are using our own service or writing batch geocoding processes. I'm happy to retire this question from stackoverflow if we believe other corporations wouldn't benefit from hearing the answer to this problem. If the answer is "buy an enterprise license and Google will manually remove the rate limit for our IP" I still think this has benefit for others. Anyone else have thoughts?

Comment: "The question is whether there is ANY way we can get an exception from Google to our specific IP address to improve the IP-based limitations given our setup? This is really a question for Google." -- I'm not saying that you should retire the question, but you're not going to get any "official" answer on Stack Overflow, which is what it seems you want.

Comment: I spoke with the sales team at Google and they don't believe this is an issue where purchasing an Enterprise License would help. They told me a Google engineer was going to check it out and get back to me, but it's been almost 3 weeks with no contact yet.

Comment: I would suggest contacting the salesperson again to check on status for you.

Comment: Why is the whole company behind the the same IP address?

Comment: I never did hear back from Google but we haven't had the problem in months now. I wish I knew why, but I'm also just content that it is working.

Answer (score 11):

A division of a **large** corporation with **tens of thousands** of employees should have an enterprise licence.

Comment: We are NOT over our API limit. This is an IP-based rate-limit we are exceeding. Buying an enterprise license would not impact the rate limit as I understand it. We are not consuming > 2500 geocoding requests per day.

Comment: From Google's geocoding strategies "You should be careful implementing server-side only, as you're very likely to run into quota issues if you geocode too fast or too much. If after designing your site, you're still running into problems with quota, you may consider a Maps API for Business license"

Comment: Let me word this another way. If too many employees across our corporation browse to third party websites that happen to be using Google maps or services on a given day, we could get blocked since everyone is on the same IP. This problem could exist even if we didn't have our own applications. I'ved submitted a request to the Google business team to see what they say. I'll just update this question once I hear back from them.

Comment: @jakejgordon that is simply not true. The client ip limit is based per map session, not per day over all.

Comment: @rickyduck You are indicating that there is not a rate limit by IP address? Given that this thing has been open since February of 2012 things could have changed by then as well. We actually haven't been blocked lately so that could also be an indication of a change as I doubt our users within our corporation are just using Google Maps less.

Comment: @jakejgordon that could very well be the case - as the time of investigation for us was only a couple of months ago. From what this page says: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#quota-limits the original page was created in June 2010, however it doesn't say when it was last updated. Either way it's certainly session based

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a limit associated with IP if you are using the client-side geocoding as described here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

> **Server-side** geocoding through the Geocoding Web Service has a quota
> of 2,500 requests per IP per day, so all requests in one day count
> against the quota. In addition, the Web Service is rate-limited, so
> that requests that come in too quickly result in blocking.
>
> **Client-side** geocoding through the browser is rate limited per map session, so the geocoding > is distributed across all your users and scales with your userbase.

A "map session" means every time the Javascript Map API is loaded. However there might be a limit on that as well, whether or not it's associated with IP / domain / sub-domain / URL still needs further clarification.

And the "rate limited" on client side doesn't mean there is a daily quota or something, I had tested this method, on a single day, it can geocode more than 2500 addresses. You will have to think and test how the "rate limit" works, my observation is it let you burst to around 10 addresses in no time, then limit you to a rate of around 1 geocode per second for the next 150 request, further request from the same "session" would take exponentially longer time.

Answer (score 0):

One possiblity is to use a batch of reverse geocode instead of a single request. Google allows up to 24 waypoints in a single direction request. Instead of sending a single reverse geocode you can wait until you have 24 reverse geocode accumulated in a batch. Or you can use Yahoo map like in this answer: [Issue in displaying static Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575053/issue-in-displaying-static-google-maps).

Comment: We are NOT over our API limit. This is an IP-based rate-limit we are exceeding. Buying an enterprise license would not impact the rate limit as I understand it. We are not consuming > 2500 geocoding requests per day. We also do not ever have more than one geocode request per session with the user. Our distributor locations are already geocoded and cached up for just this purpose.

Comment: @jakejgordon: Then this isn't a question for stackoverflow. I beleieve when you buy the license for 10k Google will give you an exception. At least you leave this impression here to be very smart guy.

Comment: @jakejgordon: I've edited my answer. You can use another map?

Answer (score 0):

I wondering if there is a lot of overlap in the requests, like everyone keeps looking up that same 50 locations?  You write a caching proxy that makes requests to a internal database first then requests from Google when the results arn't found.   This could be done at the software level changing the GeoCode call to a InternalGeoCode or maybe at the network level and catch all the requests to the Google Geocode servers and redirect them?  I'm not 100% how hard this would be to implement or if it would help maybe the requests are all unique.

Comment: Good suggestion but we actually did build in our own caching when we first rolled this out, per Google's recommendation. It is fairly easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing forward geocoding only, I suggest trying out GeocodeFarm. I just got an email from them the other day saying they would start releasing "reverse" geocoding soon too and that they are still working out the kinks. Maybe it would help you since they have no request rate limits in place and the only limit is your daily 2,500 limit, same as google... IDK. Just a suggestion..

http://www.geocodefarm.com  == the link

Answer (score 0):

The limit in standard license is in **50 to 100 QPS** (Queries per second) limit depending upon the service (i.e. Elevation service has a 50 QPS limit, Geocoding has a 100 QPS limit).
Despite you may have a higher quota you cannot perform more than 50 requests per second otherwise the server will block your IP for about 2 hours (based on my experience). The solution is to cache the requests and perform them on a scheduled basis and not upon occurrence.